# Как выполнить код, если тест завалился?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Есть тест. 
Цель теста: переводить страницу на другой язык(на странице снизу есть переключатель от гугл транслейта), и проверять как одно слово будет показано на разных языках.

Тест работает, но так как задачу еще не решили с переводом, он крашится.
И вот тут начинается проблема - этот тест не последний, и за ним идут последующие.
Соответственно, тесты начинают крашится из-за другого языка.

Вопрос: можно как-то с помощью цикла(например `while(true)`)/другие способы также интересны -  сделать так, чтобы в случае краха, он исполнил кусок кода, который как раз возвращал язык на русский?

Работаю в Selenium + TestNg + Java
Проверка нужного фрагмента делаю через:

```
assertEquals(искомое поле.getText(), "ожидаемый результат");
```

`@AfterTest` не хочется использовать.
+Есть конечно вариант запилить на время отдельный тест который возвращает, или просто убрать из набора тестов, но интересны пути решения.

П.С. пробовал обернуть `assertEquals`, но он тип `void`.
П.С.С. Сразу вопрос: также пробовал разбить данный набор тестов в `testng.xml` - нужный набор тестов перекинуть вниз.

Выглядит как-то так:

```
  <class name="1-ый класс">
            <methods>
                <include name="метод1" />
                <include name="метод2" />
                <include name="метод3" />
                <include name="метод4" />
                <include name="метод5" />
                <include name="метод6" />
            </methods>
        </class>
        <class name="2-ой класс">
            <methods>
                <include name="метод1" />
                <include name="метод2" />
                <include name="метод3" />
            </methods>
        </class>
        <class name="Еще раз указываю 1-й класс">
            <methods>
                <include name="тест с переводом" />
            </methods>
    </class>
```

В таком случае тесты идут идут идут и потом в определенном месте сами останавливаются. Написано stopped - ощущение как будто пользователь(я) сам нажал.

Comment: вообще тесты не должны зависеть от других.(почитате антипаттерн щедрые остатки).  каждый раз открывайте страницу заново. 
но также можно выполнить код после выполнения каждого метода (setUP()) либо после кадого класса (afterClass() )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тесты не должны зависеть от других.
антипаттерн

> Aнтипаттерн Щедрые Остатки (Generous Leftovers)
>
> Случай, когда один unit-тест создаёт данные, которые где-то
>   сохраняются, а другой тест их потом переиспользует. Если «генератор
>   данных» будет по какой-то причине вызван позже или пропущен, то тест,
>   использующий его данные, не пройдёт.

Каждый метод должен открыть страницу заново, чтобы выполнение одного метода не повлияло на результат другого.

Но также можно выполнить код после выполнения каждого метода (`tearDown()`), либо после кадого класса (`afterClass()` )

- `@BeforeClass` – Выполняется один раз перед тестовым классом
- `@AfterClass` – Выполняется один раз после выполнения всех методов `@Test` в классе
- `@Before` – Выполняется один раз перед любым из методов `@Test`
- `@After` – Выполняется один раз после любого метода `@Test`

[пример кода](https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-1-basic-usage/)

Comment: первый раз тоже увидел, но спасибо за более развернутый ответ.
Да, все говорят что лучше чтобы каждый отдельно работал, и тогда и зависимости отпадают и проще воcстанавливать. 
Но в данный момент, уже есть база автотестов и пока не хочу переписывать ее полностью(не сложно, но пока опасаюсь косякнуть - но  собственно так и надо делать)
Спасибо, забыл про <pre>@AfterClass</pre>

Comment: если ответ помог вам решить проблему, то можно выбрать его, нажав на галочку слева от ответа

Comment: у меня просто высвечивалось на другом вопросе, что вы сможете его оценить или выбрать правильный ответ через 2 дня, я думал тут также.

Да в AfterClass сделал через if